# Figma Plugin: callback on file updated

Tags: javascript, plugins, figma

I found the callback 'on' interesting but limiting https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/figma-on/#docsNav

I there a way to trigger an event once the file has been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the moment. The only type of update you can get is if selection changes or current page changes. Here is an example [from the docs](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/figma-on/):

```
figma.on("selectionchange", () => { console.log("changed") })
```

The method commonly used by plugins to watch for changes on nodes is polling: simply creating an interval or timer and checking if one of properties changed from the previously saved state.

```js
let interval = setInterval(checkNodes, 500) // check every 300ms

const node = figma.currentPage.selection[0] // first node in selection
let nodeWidth = node.width // store node properties to watch

function checkNodes() {
  if (nodeWidth !== node.width) {
    // width changed
  }
  nodeWidth = node.width
}
```